# Got the error error: ld returned 1 exit status when linking C++ files together

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, and I am trying to link two c++ files together, but received the error error: ld returned 1 exit status when trying to use the run build task on vs code. I am confused because neither of the files are allowing me to build.
Here is my code in the files:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y); // needed so main.cpp knows that add() is a function defined elsewhere

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is: " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using cmake however couldn't get the set up to work, I've tried redoing the files from the beginning which gave the same error

Comment: please show a [mre],  how are you building the code? What is the full compiler output and error message?

Comment: ***I've tried using cmake however couldn't get the set up to work*** Show the CMakeLists.txt that you wrote. Also did you install and enable the CMakeTools extension? Also did you look in the terminal and see which files were compiled?

Comment: ): in function `main':
C:\temp\gcc\build-mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt/../../src/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: The cmake text file is :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(test.cpp VERSION 0.1.0)
add_executable(test.cpp main.cpp)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()



set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

Comment: That means you built only the file containing `int add(int x, int y)` remember that by default VSCode only builds the active file and ignores all other source files.  The VSCode documentation explains this and tells you how to fix.

Comment: ***The cmake text file is*** Edit the question. Click on the ***Edit*** link under the tags.

Comment: Got it, how do i build both files if possible?

Comment: The VSCode documentation tells you here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)